# Disable comment moderation in multisite

Tags: comments, moderation

I'm looking for a way to disable comment moderation in wordpress completely over the whole of multisite. This is important because my site requires users to log in to use it, and every new site has to have moderation (for the first comment by a user) turned off manually.

I understand that this can be achieved in settings for each site, but I want to turn it off across the network.

Comment: Hi ameeromar, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to update all of the sites in one go as a single job (e.g. via direct DB access), or are you looking for a way to make new sites default to moderation off, or something else?

Comment: I need a way to turn of moderations completely, either for all sites, or for new sites. 

The only thing I've tried so far is to manually turn off first comment moderation in each site, but that's time consuming, I've searched for functions to control this but I can't seem to find any!